# SQL one condition OR the other

Tags: sql

I want my SQL query to only give me results if one of my conditions are true.

So for example on this query I would only want results from Berlin even if there is munchen city results.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND (City='Berlin' OR City='München');
```

The OR statement in SQL acts if one or both statements are true so i just want it to be on or the other.
Simple question but i still cant think of the answer.
I want to keep this all in one query hence the question, I know i can write another separate query

Edit
Sorry so as requested if there are Berlin results then don't select the munchen results regardless of it there are any however if there are munchen results then don't select the berlin results regardless of if there are any.
I basically have search box which either searches for the city in particular or a all cities added within a time period so just wanted to use the one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `So for example on this query I would only want results from Berlin even if there is munchen city results`.....then don't add `OR City = 'München'`?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you only want to list customers from München if there are no customers from Berlin. As soon as there is at least one customer from Berlin, no customers from München should be shown. Is that correct?

Comment: Two men down, one to go :-)

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and your desired results?

Comment: If berlin has rows show berlin. If berlin has 0 rows show Munchen?

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks for the quick reply, Yes That is exactly what i meant. Sorry for the lack of clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with Heinzi's explanation of your question from the comments

> List customers from München if there are no customers from Berlin. As soon as there is at least one customer from Berlin, no customers from München should be shown.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND ((City = 'Berlin' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' AND City = 'München'))
OR (City = 'München' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' AND City = 'Berlin')))
```

Comment: But as you said, that's @heinzi's explanation of the question, not necessarily what op really wants